# Python get touchscreen positions

Tags: python

I get mouse input with this codes:

```
from pynput import mouse

def on_click(x,y, button, pressed):

    if pressed:
        print(f"Button {button} pressed at ({x}, {y})")
    else:
        print(f"Button {button} released at ({x}, {y})")
with mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

This codes gives me mouse position in any screens.

I want to get Multi TouchInput positions like this. I have a device and it acts like a Touchscreen in my computer. I want to get positions but I don want to use kivy because when I use the kivy only program windows gives me position but I want to get positions without any game or black screen in my pc.

What should I use for this purpose?

I want to use Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code ref- https://gamedevacademy.org/unity-touch-input-tutorial/

```
void Update ()
{
    if(Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Began)
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.touches[0].position);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            if(hit.collider != null)
            {
                Color newColor = new Color(Random.Range(0.0f, 1.0f), Random.Range(0.0f, 1.0f), Random.Range(0.0f, 1.0f), 1.0);
                hit.collider.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = newColor;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any method to get with python?